# Arduino - Print file name

Tags: c++

I need my sketch to print the name of the original INO file at the beginning of execution (during `setup`).

Is it possible?  If so, what is the resource which should be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the macro `__FILE__` to get the filename that is being compiled.  That may not be your INO file, but may be some derivative of it.

```
Serial.println(__FILE__);
```

You also get some other handy macros:

```
__DATE__
The date the sketch was compiled

__TIME__ 
The time the sketch was compiled

__LINE__
The line number where __LINE__ is being used
```

The combination of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` is commonly used for debugging:

```
Serial.prinln("Error 23 at line " __LINE__ " of " __FILE__);
```